# Is inversion of an irrep equivalent to inversion of the corresponding group element?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If $g\in G$ and $R:G\rightarrow GL\left(V\right)$ is the matrix form of an irreducible representation of $G$ then is the following statement true?

$R^{-1}\left(g\right)=R\left(g^{-1}\right)$

Where the left hand side corresponds to matrix inversion of the irrep of $g$ and the right hand side corresponds to the irrep of the inverse of $g$.

Comment: I'm fairly new to group theory and representation theory, but as I understand the definition it simply states that the relationship between group elements is preserved, i.e. $R\left(g_1 g_2\right)=R\left(g_1\right)R\left(g_2\right)$. Does this imply something about the operation of inversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to consider $R(g)$ as a matrix in $GL_n(F)$. So you are really saying that $R: G \to GL_n(F)$. The question now is whether $R(g^{-1}) = R(g)^{-1}$. Here $g^{-1}$ is the inverse in the group $G$ and $R(g)^{-1}$ is the inverse as a matrix (so the inverse in the group $GL_n(F)$.

Remember that $R$ is a group homomorphism by definition. So you indeed have $$R(g^{-1}) = R(g)^{-1}.$$